# Is there a way to force tcpdump to print only hex format when reading CAN packets?

Tags: tcpdump, packets, can-bus

Although the can-utils package is available in Linux to interact with CAN network devices, I am trying to confirm if tcpdump can print just hex format when reading CAN packets without including ASCII characters?

tcpdump version 4.2.1
libpcap version 1.1.1

The only work around was I found was to direct the tcpdump output to a file then read from said file using a util like hexdump, xxd, or OD, etc.

The upper left screen is based on the script below:

```
# tcpdump -ivcan0 -s0 -x -w - -s0 -l > canpackets.hex & tail -f canpackets.hex | hexdump -vC
```

The upper right screen represents the tcpdump output using (-x) without redirecting to hexdump; which still prints ASCII.

The bottom left screen is candump; which is here just to illustrate the hex values that are generated by the cangen util in the bottom right screen.

```
while :; do ./cansend vcan0 001#1122334455667788; sleep .25; done
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to my original question.

A solution is, "Just use tshark; it works better with can packets by not printing garble." [image: tshark]